# Как подтянуть данные из DF Pandas (Выбор столбца ВПР Excel)

Tags: python, pandas

Такой вопрос: Есть пара df (в примере столбцы упразднены) нужно на выходе получить значение следующего столбца от анализируемого. Пример:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Имя': ['Стейк свинной', 'Говядина тушеная', 'Масло сливочное','Шейка свинная', 'Масло подсолнечное нерафинированное', 'Масло подсолнечное рафинированное'],
 'points': [4, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'team_name': ['Стейк', 'свинная', 'Говядина', 'сливочное', 'подсолнечное'],
  'rebounds': ['Мясо', 'Мясо','Мясо','Масло','Масло'],'points': ['q', 'w','e','r','t']})


df1['A'] = df1["Имя"].str.extract('('+'|'.join(list(df2["team_name"])) + ')')
print(df1)
```

На выходе мы получаем:

```
                                   Имя  points             A
0                        Стейк свинной       4         Стейк
1                     Говядина тушеная       4      Говядина
2                      Масло сливочное       6     сливочное
3                        Шейка свинная       8       свинная
4  Масло подсолнечное нерафинированное       9  подсолнечное
5    Масло подсолнечное рафинированное      10  подсолнечное
```

а нужно получить:

```
                                   Имя  points             A
0                        Стейк свинной       4         Мясо
1                     Говядина тушеная       4         Мясо
2                      Масло сливочное       6         Мясо
3                        Шейка свинная       8         Мясо
4  Масло подсолнечное нерафинированное       9         Масло
5    Масло подсолнечное рафинированное      10         Масло
```

- есть подозрение что нужно думать в сторону `.merge`, но выплывают ошибки:

```
ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (87297, 15)
```

В экселе вопрос одного символа в формуле, а тут...

Answer (score 1):

Для решения можно создать функцию(typo), которая будет проверять значение столбца Имя и на его основе давать значение столбцу А:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Имя': ['Стейк свинной', 'Говядина тушеная', 'Масло сливочное','Шейка свинная', 'Масло подсолнечное нерафинированное', 'Масло подсолнечное рафинированное'],
 'points': [4, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'team_name': ['Стейк', 'свинная', 'Говядина', 'сливочное', 'подсолнечное'],
  'rebounds': ['Мясо', 'Мясо','Мясо','Масло','Масло'],'points': ['q', 'w','e','r','t']})

def typo(i):
    if i in ['Стейк свинной', 'Говядина тушеная', 'Шейка свинная']:
        return 'Мясо'
    elif i in ['Масло сливочное', 'Масло подсолнечное нерафинированное', 'Масло подсолнечное рафинированное']:
        return 'Масло'


df1['A'] = np.vectorize(typo)(df1['Имя'])
print(df1)
```

Так как я не знаю все ли это типы, то функцию можно изменять, добавляя новые группы значений Имя и значение для этих групп в столбце А, так же здесь используется векторизация, тк я не знаю размер исходного датафрейма, а векторизация ускорит выполнение и будет быстрее чем тот же метод `.apply()`.

Comment: Спасибо, но метод с if else не подходит, объем фрейма огромный! Собственно по этому и решено использовать панду. И вариантов очень много думаю несколько тысяч в лучшем случае…. Плюс ситуация осложняется тем что оператор должен сам через эксель заполнять библиотеку для анализа! Собственно этот метод уже создан вопрос только в получении второго столбца! Я сейчас пытаюсь что то с мердж придумать но пока не выходит! Идея следующая через операцию выше мы получаем столбец с данными, а после джойним полученный столбец со вторым столбцом! Но пока не добился нужных результатов!

Comment: @МаксимЦарьков я мог бы попробовать несколько других способов ближе к вечеру, но мне нужны тогда оба датафрейма, чтоб примерно понимать, сколько разных групп есть типа масло, мясо и тд, ну и чтоб в целом понимать какими способами лучше воспользоваться в данном случае

Comment: @МаксимЦарьков здесь можно было бы воспользоваться джоином, но для этого нужно чтоб либо в первом датафрейме появился столбец ‘team_name’ либо во втором датафрейме столбец ‘Имя’ тогда бы их можно было мерджить по этим столбцам. Но это сложно сделать, тк алгоритм получения team_name из Имя непонятен, тк из Имя берут одно слово, но оно отличается по порядку в строке, в принципе есть еще вариант решения, но он может занять много времени…

Comment: К сожалению реальный фрейм я дать не могу! Если Вы не в теме данного вопроса не хочу Вас напрягать! Сам попробую найти способ, если что напишу решение

Comment: Вообще странно что нет базовых принципов в pd которые позволяют без дополнительных конструкций решить такую простую задачу (как для впр эксель) есть стойкое ощущение что все таки какое то решение (из коробки есть) шуршу документацию…

Answer (score 1):

Ну да, можно использовать `merge`

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Имя': ['Стейк свинной', 'Говядина тушеная', 'Масло сливочное', 'Шейка свинная',
                            'Масло подсолнечное нерафинированное', 'Масло подсолнечное рафинированное'],
                    'points': [4, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'team_name': ['Стейк', 'свинная', 'Говядина', 'сливочное', 'подсолнечное'],
                    'rebounds': ['Мясо', 'Мясо', 'Мясо', 'Масло', 'Масло'], 'points': ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't']})

df1['A'] = df1["Имя"].str.extract('(' + '|'.join(list(df2["team_name"])) + ')').merge(df2, left_on=0, right_on='team_name')['rebounds']
print(df1)
```

```
                                   Имя  points      A
0                        Стейк свинной       4   Мясо
1                     Говядина тушеная       4   Мясо
2                      Масло сливочное       6  Масло
3                        Шейка свинная       8   Мясо
4  Масло подсолнечное нерафинированное       9  Масло
5    Масло подсолнечное рафинированное      10  Масло
```

Comment: Алексей Р Спасибо за идею, делал почти то же кроме ['rebounds'] но все равно не работает правильно (программа не корректно прогружает столбец) сейчас пытаюсь понять почему! Как выясню почему отпишусь! Есть подозрение что дело  в left_on=0 но это пока не точно! в части боевого фрейма программа просто скопом проставляет значения! до определенного момента! В любом случае спасибо! Всем!

Comment: Алексей Р понял в чем ошибка, нужно было добавить параметр в моем случае левый! И все заработало! Большое спасибо всем! Уверен этот пост поможет многим! ПС  Без how='left' Программа странно выдавала имена пытался смоделировать - не вышло что бы понять где именно прога сворачивает не туда но так и не нашел принцип некорректной обработки(скорее всего это связано с параметром how по умолчанию)!